# Passing the values of foreach from controller to view

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach

I am trying to pass the foreach values from the controller to view but I recieved only an empty array. In the below code based on the values in the foreach I have executed a query and I want to set the value so that I can use it in the view.

```
foreach($logresponse as $row1){
    $customerid = $row1['customerid'];
    $topicid = $row1['topicid'];
    $todolistid = $row1['todolistid'];
    $sqlQry="select leadid,customerid as leadcustid,formname from lead_frontend where customerid='$customerid' order by leadid DESC limit 1";
    $leadInfo[] = $this->execute_flatten($sqlQry);
    if($topicid == 1){
        $query2="SELECT a.*,b.username,b.user_id,b.group_id,b.email as salesmanemail,d.email,d.phone1,e.subject,e.subject1,e.content,e.embed_template FROM todolist_frontend as a LEFT JOIN users_backend as b ON a.salesmanid=b.user_id LEFT JOIN customer as c ON c.customerid=a.customerid LEFT JOIN customer_address as d ON d.customerid=a.customerid LEFT JOIN admin_email_action as e ON a.combination_id=e.combination_id where a.todolistid='$todolistid'";
    }
    else if($topicid == 2){
        $query2="SELECT a.*,b.username,b.user_id,b.group_id,b.email as salesmanemail,d.email,d.phone1,e.subject,e.subject1,e.call_info as content FROM todolist_frontend as a INNER JOIN users_backend as b ON a.salesmanid=b.user_id INNER JOIN customer as c ON c.customerid=a.customerid INNER JOIN customer_address as d ON d.customerid=a.customerid INNER JOIN admin_call_action as e ON a.combination_id=e.combination_id where a.todolistid='$todolistid'";
    }
    else if($topicid == 18){
        $query2="SELECT a.*,b.username,b.user_id,b.group_id,b.email as salesmanemail,d.email,d.phone1,e.subject,e.subject1,e.call_info as content FROM todolist_frontend as a INNER JOIN users_backend as b ON a.salesmanid=b.user_id INNER JOIN customer as c ON c.customerid=a.customerid INNER JOIN customer_address as d ON d.customerid=a.customerid INNER JOIN admin_managercall_action as e ON a.combination_id=e.combination_id where a.todolistid='$todolistid'";
    }
    else{
        $query2="SELECT a.*,b.username,b.user_id,b.group_id,b.email as salesmanemail,d.email,d.phone1,e.content,e.subject1,f.emailname as subject,g.mailername AS mailersubject FROM todolist_frontend as a LEFT JOIN users_backend as b ON a.salesmanid=b.user_id LEFT JOIN customer as c ON c.customerid=a.customerid LEFT JOIN customer_address as d ON d.customerid=a.customerid LEFT JOIN admin_mailer_action as e ON a.combination_id=e.combination_id LEFT JOIN emailtype_backend as f ON e.subject=f.emailid LEFT JOIN mailer_backend AS g ON e.subject = g.mailerid where a.todolistid='$todolistid'";
    }
    $result = $this->execute_flatten($query2);

    $subjecttodo = array();
    foreach ($result as $res1){
        if($res1['topicid'] == 1 && !empty($res1['subject'])){
            $subject1 = $res1['subject'];
            $sub_qry="select emailname from emailtype_backend where emailid=$subject1";
            $subject_result=$this->execute_flatten($sub_qry);
            $subjecttodo=isset($subject_result['0']['emailname']) ? $subject_result['0']['emailname'] : "";
        }
        if($res1['topicid'] == 2 || $res1['topicid'] == 18){
            $subjecttodo=$res1['subject'];
        }
        if($res1['topicid'] == 8){
            $subjecttodo=$res1['mailersubject'];
        }
    $this->set('subjecttodo', $subjecttodo);   
    }
    $this->set('leadInfo', $leadInfo);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a large amount of sql in your controller code - that's not a good thing (why there is sql at all, is also a bit weird since the queries are pretty simple). At the very least, all that logic should be in a model method, which the controller calls.

Comment: Yes you are right. For now I am working with the logics. Later I need to change all these simple codes to cakePHP format. Anyway thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($logresponse as $key => $row1){
            $customerid = $row1['customerid'];
            $topicid = $row1['topicid'];
            $todolistid = $row1['todolistid'];

            $sqlQry="select leadid,customerid as leadcustid,formname from lead_frontend where customerid='$customerid' order by leadid DESC limit 1";
            $leadInfo = $this->execute_flatten($sqlQry);            
            $logresponse[$key]['formname'] =  isset($leadInfo[0]['formname']) ? $leadInfo[0]['formname'] : '';

            if($topicid == 1){
                $query2="SELECT a.*,b.username,b.user_id,b.group_id,b.email as salesmanemail,d.email,d.phone1,e.subject,e.subject1,e.content,e.embed_template FROM todolist_frontend as a LEFT JOIN users_backend as b ON a.salesmanid=b.user_id LEFT JOIN customer as c ON c.customerid=a.customerid LEFT JOIN customer_address as d ON d.customerid=a.customerid LEFT JOIN admin_email_action as e ON a.combination_id=e.combination_id where a.todolistid='$todolistid'";
            }else if($topicid == 2){
                $query2="SELECT a.*,b.username,b.user_id,b.group_id,b.email as salesmanemail,d.email,d.phone1,e.subject,e.subject1,e.call_info as content FROM todolist_frontend as a INNER JOIN users_backend as b ON a.salesmanid=b.user_id INNER JOIN customer as c ON c.customerid=a.customerid INNER JOIN customer_address as d ON d.customerid=a.customerid INNER JOIN admin_call_action as e ON a.combination_id=e.combination_id where a.todolistid='$todolistid'";
            }else if($topicid == 18){
                $query2="SELECT a.*,b.username,b.user_id,b.group_id,b.email as salesmanemail,d.email,d.phone1,e.subject,e.subject1,e.call_info as content FROM todolist_frontend as a INNER JOIN users_backend as b ON a.salesmanid=b.user_id INNER JOIN customer as c ON c.customerid=a.customerid INNER JOIN customer_address as d ON d.customerid=a.customerid INNER JOIN admin_managercall_action as e ON a.combination_id=e.combination_id where a.todolistid='$todolistid'";
            }else{
                $query2="SELECT a.*,b.username,b.user_id,b.group_id,b.email as salesmanemail,d.email,d.phone1,e.content,e.subject1,f.emailname as subject,g.mailername AS mailersubject FROM todolist_frontend as a LEFT JOIN users_backend as b ON a.salesmanid=b.user_id LEFT JOIN customer as c ON c.customerid=a.customerid LEFT JOIN customer_address as d ON d.customerid=a.customerid LEFT JOIN admin_mailer_action as e ON a.combination_id=e.combination_id LEFT JOIN emailtype_backend as f ON e.subject=f.emailid LEFT JOIN mailer_backend AS g ON e.subject = g.mailerid where a.todolistid='$todolistid'";
            }
            $result = $this->execute_flatten($query2);
            foreach ($result as $res1){
                if($res1['topicid'] == 1 && !empty($res1['subject'])){
                    $subject1 = $res1['subject'];
                    $sub_qry="select emailname from emailtype_backend where emailid=$subject1";
                    $subject_result=$this->execute_flatten($sub_qry);
                    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($subject_result); echo '</pre>';
                    $subjecttodo=isset($subject_result[0]['emailname']) ? $subject_result[0]['emailname'] : '';
                }
                if($res1['topicid'] == 2 || $res1['topicid'] == 18){
                    $subjecttodo=$res1['subject'];
                }
                if($res1['topicid'] == 8){
                    $subjecttodo=$res1['mailersubject'];
                }
            }
            $logresponse[$key]['subjecttodo'] =  isset($subjecttodo) ? $subjecttodo : '';

        }
$this->set('logresponse',$logresponse);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly as I expected! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First check whether you are getting values into variables `$subjecttodo` and  `$leadInfo` inside foreach loop. Then assign that values into Array.

```
 $subjecttodoArray[] = $subjecttodo; 
 $leadInfoArray[] = $leadInfo;
```

After that in Controller function try to pass this Array set like you do

```
$this->set('subjecttodo', $subjecttodoArray); 
$this->set('leadInfo', $leadInfoArray);
```

Then try to print Array values inside view like this

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($subjecttodo);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($subjecttodo);
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you see my code, you could see I did the same thing but the problem I am facing is I am getting empty values when I checked it.

Comment: `$subjecttodo=$res1['subject']; ... $this->set('subjecttodo', $subjecttodo);` In the question  you are overwriting this variable in a loop - this answer is appending to a variable in a loop and calling set once. In fact, in the question it looks like you're calling `set` many times (many more than 2) with the same variable key name. Whatever you set these variables with _last_ is what you'll see in the view.